# Is there a tool or library for organizing/alphabetizing CSS, JSON objects, and so forth?

Tags: .net, css, json, ide

### Background

I am working on a commercial code base that now has thousands of lines of JSON objects in the primary code (not as data) and hundreds of lines of CSS.

Due to the size of the code, it is getting tough to manage and I would like to alphabetize the JSON objects and CSS so that elements of these items are easier to find while coding.

I am thinking of just quickly writing a little web app or Windows forms app to do this.

### Question

Does such a tool already exist?  I don't want to waste time coding it if the code is already out there.  If I *do* code it, I will be happy to share the code with anyone who is interested.

### To be clear:

I am only looking to run a string of my primary coded (JSON, CSS, so on) through a tool to clean it up and organize it by alphabetization and maybe some formatting.  I am #NOT# looking to sort a JSON object to be displayed to the end-user.  I know how to do that.  I simply want to know if there is a pre-existing tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

this:

http://styleneat.com/

seems to allow you to sort your css alphabetically (along with some other css beautifier features that should still improve its readability) albeit it warns about using caution. hope that helps, I don't know about JSON though!